How to Add a Scrollbar to a Status Container When Content Exceeds 100% Height Without Setting a Fixed Height?
I'm working on a responsive layout where I want the .status container to have a scrollbar if its content exceeds the available space. However, I don't want to set a fixed height for the .status container since the layout needs to be flexible and responsive. I'm looking for a solution primarily using HTML and CSS, but I'm open to JavaScript, TypeScript, or Angular solutions if necessary.
In this example, each .status container should display a scrollbar if the content exceeds the available height. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this without setting a fixed height.
Is there a way to make the .status container handle overflow correctly in this scenario?
Here is the code I'm working with:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;
            row-gap: 20px;
        }

        .content-1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .content-2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: pink;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
            gap: 20px;
        }

        .status {
            height: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 5px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        .card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: green;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-1"></div>
        <div class="content-2">
            <div class="status">
                <div>Status</div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <div>Status</div>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <div>Status</div>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <div>Status</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Which of the height of content-2, container, body, and html is the standard? Setting the height of .status to 100% allows you to follow the height of your parent and use 'overflow: auto'. Alternatively, you can add scrolling when the number of elements inside the .status exceeds the desired number.

@NINE What do you mean by standard?

If there are no criteria, such as setting the maximum height to viewport-height, the child will also continue to grow.

@NINE if I add max-height: 100vh; or max-height: 100%; to the body, the child (cards) still continue to grow.

Of course, you have to limit the height according to that standard so that you can get the result you want. It's already in the answer

If you don't need individual scroll bars for each .status container, you can apply the following CSS changes:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.content-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.status {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-1"></div>
    <div class="content-2">
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



This will ensure that the .content-2 container has a scrollbar when necessary, without affecting each individual .status container.
However, if you need individual scroll bars for each .status container, you can apply the following changes:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;
  row-gap: 20px;
}

.content-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.status {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-1"></div>
    <div class="content-2">
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        <div>Status</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Note: Applying overflow-y: scroll; to the .content-2 container will result in an additional scrollbar at the bottom, which will not be useful but will appear due to the overflow-y: scroll property on .content-2.
